# In DOM, ID can not be used in "for" loop because ID can only be used once in one page, how can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, dom

I use

```
for(var i=0; i<hotelinresult.length; i++)
```

then my html is this:

```
<p id="hotelin-title" class="hotelin-title"><%= hotelinresult[i].title %></p>
```

I write a function setEllipsis() to make every `<p>` has ... at the end of `<p>` by using `getElementById('hotelin-title')`

BUT...function occurs just in the first data, i guess that's because ID ID can only be used once in one page. How can make my function work in the loop instead of using `getElementById('hotelin-title')`?

Comment: Use a `class` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName()` to return a collection of HTML elements you can iterate through. You'll need to set a class on every element you want to apply your code to.

```
<div class=ellipsis>Some text</div>
<div class=ellipsis>Some more text</div>

<script>
var els = document.getElementsByClassName('ellipsis');
for (var i=0; i<els.length; i++) {
  someFunction(els[i]);
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but getElementsByClassName can not work in IE?

Comment: It's supported by IE9+. Her'es the [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hotelin-title')
```

ID's can only be used once on a page

Also, it would be even easier to use jQuery for this.  You could simply access all elements via:

```
$('.hotelin-title')
```